# How to instantiate Y for a digit-counting predicate?

Tags: prolog

I have a method that goes through a number X, and counts how many of its digits are even (which is the purpose of the Y parameter)

```
count_even(0,_). %base case
count_even(X,Y) :- mod(X,2)=:=0,%recursive case
    Y1 is Y + 1,
    X1 is X // 10, %if X is even
    count_even(X1,Y1)
    ;   mod(X,2)\==0, %if X is odd
    X1 is X // 10,
    count_even(X1,Y).
```

of course, its easy to get results by calling count_even(*insert any number*, 0) and add a write(y) to the base case, but **I need to make sure the method works when you put in a variable for the second parameter**, like count_even(*insert any number*, **A**)

of course, that would require Y to be instantiated, but putting a simple Y is 0 in the recursive method will result in Y always being 0 or 1, and I don't want that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn around the calculation and instantiate `Y` in the base case with `0`. In each step with an even digit it gets incremented.

Other problems: In the recursive case you have to make sure that `X > 0`, otherwise you get additional incorrect answers during backtracking. Also, the arithmetic *not equal* is `=\=` (`\==` instead unifies terms, negated, which is also true for `mod(8,2)==0`). That also gives you additional incorrect results.

Fixed code:

```
count_even(0,0). %base case
count_even(X,Y) :- X > 0, X1 is X // 10, %recursive case
                  ((mod(X,2)=:=0, count_even(X1,Y1), Y is Y1 + 1); %if X is even
                   (mod(X,2)=\=0, count_even(X1,Y))). %if X is odd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
even_digits( N, Y ) :-  % the general case
    N > 0,              % - for N > 0,
    N1 is div(N,10) ,   % - get all digits to the left of the one's place
    D  is mod(N,10) ,   % - get the one's digit
    even_digits(N1,T) , % - recurse down on N1
    ( is_even(D)        % - if the one's digit is even
      -> Y is T+1       % - add 1 to the earlier result
      ;  Y is T         % - otherwise, we're done.
    ).                  % Easy!
even_digits( 0, 0 ).    % the base case. The question is... is zero even, odd, or signless. I've decided that it is signless here.

is_even(N) :- 0 =:= mod(N,2).
```

But that leaves you in a strange place with zero. Zero is the point at which we've run out of digits in a positive number, but it is also a digit in and of itself.

You might find it easier to treat the number as an atom and break it up into a list of digits.

```
even_digits( N, R ) :-
    number_chars(N,Ds),
    even_digits( Ds, 0 , R ).

even_digits( []     , N , N ).
even_digits( [D|Ds] , T , N ) :-
    ( member( D, ['0','2','4','6','8'] )
      -> T1 is T+1
      ;  T1 is T
    ),
    even_digits(Ds, T1, N).
```

This works for negative numbers, zero, numbers with fractional values.